# How to run reprex in Rstudio? I encountered an error

Tags: r, rstudio, reprex

after installation the package,

```
> library(reprex)
> (y <- 1:4)
[1] 1 2 3 4
> mean(y)
[1] 2.5
> reprex()
Rendering reprex...
Error: callr subprocess failed: <text>:18:7: unexpected 'in'
17: #+ reprex-body
18: Error in
          ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell for sure, but it looks like you might be running code in the console and then running `reprex()`. Instead, do one of the following

1. Place your code inside the `reprex` function:

   ```
   reprex({
     (y=1:4)
     mean(y)
   })
   ```

   You can do this directly in the console or in a script file in the RStudio "source" pane. Then run the code.
2. Type your code in an R script file in the RStudio `source` pane:

   ```
   (y=1:4)
   mean(y)
   ```

   Then copy it to the clipboard. Then run `reprex()` in the console.

Either way, you should then see the following in the `Viewer` pane. The output below will also have been placed in your clipboard, so that you can paste it into any other location:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. my vote up does not change the publicly displayed post score because I am new to so with less than 15 reputation